# Definition of a Zero Divisor Clarification

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with an identity. An element $a \in R$ is a zero divisor if $a \neq 0$ and there exists a $b \neq 0$ such that $ab = 0$ or $ba = 0$.

Does every ring have a zero element and is this element one such that $0*a = a*0 = 0$ for all elements $a \in R$?

Comment: Yes: every ring has a zero elements $0$, this holds by definition. This is the element satisfying $a+0=0+a=a$ for all $a$. Now $0$ has another property: every element multiplied by $0$ gives you $0$ (i.e. for all $a$ you have $a\cdot 0 = 0 \cdot a = 0$), but this is not a definition, it is a consequence of ring axioms. Again, using ring axioms, you can prove that $0$ is the unique element of the ring having this property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of a ring requires that the set $R$ form an abelian group under addition, so the $0$ element is required as the identity under this operation. This element is called the "absorbing element" for multiplication, since for any $r \in R$, $r \times 0 = 0 \times r = 0$, so that $0$ 'absorbs' all ring elements under multiplication.

The definition of a zero divisor is exactly what it says on the tin; recall that normally we say $a \vert b$ if we can write $b = ak$ so that the quotient $k = b/a \in \Bbb Z$.

Let $b = 0$. Then we have $a\vert 0$, that is, there exist elements $a, k \in R$ (where $R$ is the ring in question) such that $0 = ak$ but neither $a$ nor $k$ is equal to $0$, or in other words, $a$ divides $0$ (or $k$ divides $0$) and so $a$ and $k$ are "zero divisors".